# I can not get the encoding of ffmpeg

Tags: ios, encoding, ffmpeg, media

The media is being developed based on ffmpeg.
I can not do video encode.
An error message is displayed, indicating an invalid argument, which receives frame via `av_buffersink_get_frame` of avfilter and creates `avcodec_send_frame`.

You are trying some of the methods, but only messages like Continue are displayed.

```
 frame = av_frame_alloc();
 ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(buffersink_ctx, frame);
 if (ret < 0) {
      NSLog(@"buffersink not get frame");
 }
```